# After automatizing drop down list, the information brings a different date format

Tags: javascript, datetime, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm beginning to learn JavaScript and I've been already implementing my knowledge into a  project for my family business.

My company has several clients, we sell them several materials, but the prices change several times along the week/month. I have already developed a Spreadsheet in which I register every single delivery we do to different clients. In one column I write the name of the client and in the following columns, I write the date of the delivery and the date in which the last price was updated for the system to go and look for the date in a prices matrix and automatically bring the price according to the material I selected in another cell from the same row.

What I coded was based on a YouTube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G_aYSAX3i7M  which makes my life easier. I don't have to go look for the dates of the updated prices in another sheet, but just selecting it from the dropdown list (I attach picture):

[image]

My problem is that my format of my column is `dd/mm/yyyy`, I'm using the `INDIRECT` function and the source data is in the correct format, but when it brings the data to the cell that it is needed it changes to `mm/dd/yyyy`.

**Here is the code:**

```
function onEdit() { 
  var start = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet(); 
  var current = start.getActiveCell()
  var list = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('INDIRECT'); 
  var main = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('JASACO'); 

  if (current.getColumn()==5)
  {
    
    var choice = current.getValue()
    list.getRange(2,9).setValue(choice)

   
    var point = current.offset(0,5)
    var items = list.getRange(2,10,300)
    var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(items,true).build();
    point.setDataValidation(rule)
  }  
}
```

When the drop-down list is shown, the data already changed its format even though the source is in the correct format. How can I make the dropdown list show the data in the `dd/mm/yyy`y format?

Comment: please @NahumJaimeSanchez provide a sample we can reproduce (share the link). Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please add some sample data input, the corresponding expected result the spreadsheet regional settings and the cells number format settings. Usually it's very convenient to include a link to a demo spreadsheet shared with anyone with the link able to view in order to make it easier for others to reproduce the problem.